# Holding a first value in a column while another column equals a value?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I would like to hold the first value in a column while another column does not equal zero. For Column B, values alternate between -1, 0, 1. For Column C, values equal any integer. The objective is holding the first value of Column C while Column B equals zero. The current DataFrame is as follows:

```
   A  B C 
1  8  1 9  
2  2  1 1  
3  3  0 7  
4  9  0 8  
5  5  0 9  
6  6  0 1  
7  1  1 9  
8  6  1 10 
9  3  0 4  
10 8  0 8  
11 5  0 9  
12 6  0 10
```

The resulting DataFrame should be as follows:

```
   A  B C 
1  8  1 9  
2  2  1 1  
3  3  0 7  
4  9  0 7  
5  5  0 7  
6  6  0 7  
7  1  1 9  
8  6  1 10 
9  3  0 4  
10 8  0 4  
11 5  0 4  
12 6  0 4 
13 3  1 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first create `NaN`s by condition in column `C` and then add values by `ffill`:

```
mask = (df['B'].shift().fillna(False)).astype(bool) | (df['B'])
df['C'] = df.loc[mask, 'C']
df['C'] = df['C'].ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
    A  B   C
1   8  1   9
2   2  1   1
3   3  0   7
4   9  0   7
5   5  0   7
6   6  0   7
7   1  1   9
8   6  1  10
9   3  0   4
10  8  0   4
11  5  0   4
12  6  0   4
13  3  1   9
```

Or use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) and if type of all values is integer, add `astype`:

```
mask = (df['B'].shift().fillna(False)).astype(bool) | (df['B'])
df['C'] = df['C'].where(mask).ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
    A  B   C
1   8  1   9
2   2  1   1
3   3  0   7
4   9  0   7
5   5  0   7
6   6  0   7
7   1  1   9
8   6  1  10
9   3  0   4
10  8  0   4
11  5  0   4
12  6  0   4
13  3  1   9
```

Comment: Both solutions are correct as implemented. Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: I think not, because 9 is missing :( Check new solution

Comment: I missed that, thanks. For my purposes, this solution works, as Column C is a helper column to calculate a new value. It seems there is a mismatch in the row extending below Column B's last 0 value, which is possibly due to the shifts on Column B. Thanks again!